# Get all key/value pairs from data attr that have the same prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am working on a platform and would like to unify and standardize some behaviour throughout the platform...the data- attribute in the html elements will play a huge part...

So lets say I have a button:

```
<a href="..." class="btn" data-tip="My button" data-modal_tile="Foo" data-templade_data_id="14" data-templade_data_action="reset">...</a>
```

now, my Javascripts handles the behaviour of this button.

What I would like is to get set a template_data array, that would give me all key/value pairs from the data- attribute that have the same prefix (data-template_data_)...
so in my example I would get:

```
{
    id: "14",
    action : "reset"
}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var array = [];
$( ".btn" ).each( function(){
    var obj = {};
    $.each(this.attributes, function() 
    {
        if(this.name.indexOf( "data-templade_data_" ) == 0 ) 
        {
            var key = this.name.replace( "data-templade_data_", "" );
            obj[ key ] = this.value;
        }
    });
    array.push( obj );
} );
```

Comment: ok, thanks... something like this... a little shorter since jQuery lets you access data with $(el).data() so I would iterate only trough data ones.. it is quite straight forward though... thanks

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
hyphened: function(prefix) { // prefix = data or myplugin
    var attributes = {};
    $.each(this.get(0).attributes, function(index, attrib) {
        if(attrib.name.indexOf(prefix+"-")==0) {
            var key = attrib.name.replace(prefix+"-","");
            attributes[key] = attrib.value;
        }
    });

    return attributes;
}
```

});